# Laravel return images link from the Storage but links is not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on Laravel project API and I am using the `Storage` to store images and I need to retrieve the links and send the links to the frontend, but when I use the links in `src` img attribute it's not working

```
$destination = Destination::findOrFail($id);

$destination_images = $destination->destination_images;

$urls = [];

foreach ($destination_images as $destination_image) {
    $link = Storage::disk('public')->path($destination_image->img);
    array_push($urls, $link);
}

return response()->json($url);
```

This is the array of links

```
[
    "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\rindextwo\\storage\\app/public\\destination-F2QSioUxe2.jpeg",
    "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\rindextwo\\storage\\app/public\\destination-vRvimgsiMJ.png"
]
```

When I enter the links in browser it shows the images successfully

but when I use it in the Angular project it's not working

Is there anything or process I must done before passing the links to the frontend?

This is the browser dev-tools inspection of the image when I enter the image link manually in the browser search bar

[image: Browser Inspect]

The whole controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin\dashboard\setup\locations;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\admin\dashboard\setup\locations\Destination;
use App\Models\admin\dashboard\setup\locations\DestinationImage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ApiDestinationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $destinations = Destination::get();

        return response()->json($destinations);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:100',
            'description' => 'nullable|string',
            'fileSource' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $errors = $validator->errors();
            return response()->json($errors);
        }

        $destination = Destination::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'description' => $request->description
        ]);

        foreach ($request->fileSource as $img) {
            $extension = explode('/', explode(':', substr($img, 0, strpos($img, ';')))[1])[1];
            $replace = substr($img, 0, strpos($img, ',')+1);
            $image = str_replace($replace, '', $img);
            $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
            $imageName = 'destination-' . Str::random(10).'.'.$extension;
            Storage::disk('public')->put($imageName, base64_decode($image));
            DestinationImage::create([
                'destination_id' => $destination->id,
                'img' => $imageName
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json('Destination Created Successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $destination = Destination::findOrFail($id);

        $destination_images = $destination->destination_images;

        $urls = [];

        foreach ($destination_images as $destination_image) {
            //$link = Storage::disk('public')->path($destination_image->img);
            $link = public_path('storage/'.$destination_image->img);
            array_push($urls, $link);
        }

        $response = [];

        array_push($response, $destination, $urls);

        return response()->json($response);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'nullable|string|max:100',
            'description' => 'nullable|string'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $errors = $validator->errors();
            return response()->json($errors);
        }

        $destination = Destination::findOrFail($id);

        $destination->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'description' => $request->description
        ]);

        return response()->json('Destination Updated Successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $destination = Destination::findOrFail($id);

        $destination->delete();

        return response()->json('Destination Deleted Successfully');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please inspect your image link by browser developer tools and send it here.

Comment: return response()->json($url); ($url or $urls ???)

Comment: @MartinAmu I modified the question with the inspection bro

Comment: As you see your link is not correct.

Comment: @MartinAmu But the image is showing successfully
Please provide me with the solution

Comment: @OsamaAmr, the reason it's not showing in Angular is because the absolute path not working in angular, when you run `php artisan storage:link`, it will create `public/storage/` link, and you need `public_path('storage');` to get the image path, that should look something like from the URL project is running. For example: `localhost:3000/public/storage/destination-F2QSioUxe2.jpeg`

Comment: You don't need absolute paths. So try changing `$link = public_path('storage/'.$destination_image->img);` to `$link = Storage::disk('public')->url($destination_image->img);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute paths (filesystem paths) won't work with **src** attribute on **img** tag.

The following will always return absolute (filesystem) paths

```php
Storage::disk('public')->path($destination_image->img);

//Or

public_path('storage/'.$destination_image->img);
```

To get the relative path you can

```php
$link = Storage::disk('public')->url($destination_image->img);
```

[Laravel Docs - Filesystem - File Urls](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-urls)

Or use the **asset** helper to get the fully qualified url

```php
$link = asset('storage/' . trim($destination_image->img, '/'));
```

[Laravel Docs - Helpers - asset](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-asset)

Or use the **url** helper to get the fully qualified url

```php
$link = url('storage/' . trim($destination_image->img, '/'));
```

[Laravel Docs - Helpers - url](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-url)

For your particular use case you can define an accessor on the **DestinationImage** model  like

```php
class DestinationImage extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['src'];

    public function getSrcAttribute()
    {
        return Storage::disk('public')->url($this->img);
    }

    //rest of the model code
}
```

Then in the controller you can eager load the relation

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $destination = Destination::with('destination_images')->findOrFail($id);

    return response()->json($destination);

    //Or since Eloquent models are Jsonable
    //return $destination;
}
```

And you can access the **src** attribute on the **destination_images** records in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:100',
            'description' => 'nullable|string',
            'fileSource' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $errors = $validator->errors();
            return response()->json($errors);
        }
        
        $image = $request->file('fileSource');

        $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName();       
        $destinationPath = public_path('storage');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $imageName);
        
        Destination::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'image' => $image
        ]);
        
        return response()->json('Destination Created Successfully');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks bro but it's giving the same response and the same result
I edited the question and added the whole controller code for you to examine it

Comment: Please check it again with changes in your controller.

Comment: exception: "Error"
file: "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\rindextwo\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\admin\\dashboard\\setup\\locations\\ApiDestinationController.php"
line: 59
message: "Call to a member function move() on string"

Comment: I removed the Storage::disk........ and add the new two lines and I got this error

Comment: if you have problems with move, you can use save ->save($destinationPath.'/'.$imageName);

Comment: if you want to upload multiple images then use foreach loop and key